# How do i connect points on Sketch 3?

Tags: sketch-app

Is there a way to connect points like illustrator in sketch? Also is there an easier way to delete a line from a shape without clicking open path?

[image: How do I connect vector points]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Edit: earlier I told you there wasn't a feature in Sketch that allowed you to connect two paths. **There is.** I did a little digging and the feature is hidden away under "Layer -> Paths" menu.

Regardless, for more complex editing on your paths, I recommend you use Affinity Designer or Illustrator.